# PostgreSQL using different index for same query

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a SQL query which is using inner join on two tables and filtering data based on several params. Going by the query plan, for different values of query params (like different date range), Postgres is using different index.

I am aware of the fact that Postgres determines if the index has to be used or not, depending on the number or rows in the result set. But why does Postgres choose to use different index for same query. The query time varies by a factor of 10, between the two cases. How can I optimise the query? As Postgres does not allows the user to define the index to be used in a query.

Edit:

```
explain (analyze, buffers, verbose) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookings" INNER JOIN "hotels" ON "hotels"."id" = "bookings"."hotel_id" WHERE "bookings"."hotel_id" = 37016 AND (bookings.status in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12)) AND (bookings.source in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70) or bookings.status in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13)) AND (
bookings.source in (4,66,65)
OR
date(timezone('+05:30',bookings.created_at))>checkin
OR
(
( date(timezone('+05:30',bookings.created_at))=checkin
and
extract (epoch from COALESCE(cancellation_time,NOW())-bookings.created_at)>600
)
OR
( date(timezone('+05:30',bookings.created_at))<checkin
and
extract (epoch from COALESCE(cancellation_time,NOW())-bookings.created_at)>600
and
(
extract (epoch from ((bookings.checkin||' '||hotels.checkin_time)::timestamp -COALESCE(cancellation_time,bookings.checkin))) < extract(epoch from '16 hours'::interval)
OR
(DATE(bookings.checkout)-DATE(bookings.checkin))*(COALESCE(bookings.oyo_rooms,0)+COALESCE(bookings.owner_rooms,0)) > 3
)
)
)
) AND (bookings.checkin >= '2018-11-21') AND (bookings.checkin <= '2019-05-19') AND "bookings"."hotel_id" = '37016' AND "bookings"."status" IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 12);
```

QueryPlan : https://explain.depesz.com/s/SPeb

```
explain (analyze, buffers, verbose) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bookings" INNER JOIN "hotels" ON "hotels"."id" = 37016 WHERE "bookings"."hotel_id" = 37016 AND (bookings.status in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12)) AND (bookings.source in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70) or bookings.status in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13)) AND (
bookings.source in (4,66,65)
OR
date(timezone('+05:30',bookings.created_at))>checkin
OR
(
( date(timezone('+05:30',bookings.created_at))=checkin
and
extract (epoch from COALESCE(cancellation_time,now())-bookings.created_at)>600
)
OR
( date(timezone('+05:30',bookings.created_at))<checkin
and
extract (epoch from COALESCE(cancellation_time,now())-bookings.created_at)>600
and
(extract (epoch from ((bookings.checkin||' '||hotels.checkin_time)::timestamp -COALESCE(cancellation_time,bookings.checkin))) < extract(epoch from '16 hours'::interval)
OR
(DATE(bookings.checkout)-DATE(bookings.checkin))*(COALESCE(bookings.oyo_rooms,0)+COALESCE(bookings.owner_rooms,0)) > 3
)
)
)
) AND (bookings.checkin >= '2018-11-22') AND (bookings.checkin <= '2019-05-19') AND "bookings"."hotel_id" = '37016' AND "bookings"."status" IN (0,1,2,3,4,12);
```

QueryPlan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/DWD

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , edited the post.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the two conditions at the end `AND "bookings"."hotel_id" = '37016'
  AND "bookings"."status" IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 12)` are useless because there is `WHERE "bookings"."hotel_id" = 37016` at the beginning and a larger status range as well: `AND (bookings.status IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12))`

Comment: It seems that with the bigger date range, the optimizer expects more rows and thus uses a different index. Does running `analyze bookings` (or `vacuum analyze bookings`) change anything?

Comment: The different `IN` lists may also have an impact,

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to this problem. I am querying on the basis of more than 10 possible values of a column (**status** in this case). If I break this query into multiple sub-queries each querying upon only 1 status value and aggregate the result using union all, then the query plan executed uses optimized index for each subquery.

Results: The query time decreased by 10 times by this change.

Possible explanation for this behaviour, the query planner fetches less number of rows for each subquery and uses the optimized index in this case. I am not sure about if this is the correct explanation.